# How do I print XPath value?

Tags: ruby, xpath, mechanize

I want to print the contents of an XPath node. Here is what I have:

```
require "mechanize"
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.get("http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/snowglobefaq")
puts agent.xpath("//*[@id='item_52b3985a70d58']/div[4]")
```

This returns: `<main>: undefined method xpath for #<Mechanize:0x2fa18c0> (NoMethodError)`.

I just started using Mechanize and have no idea what I'm doing, however, I've used Watir and thought this would work but it didn't.

Comment: You could use it like:  `agent.page.at("//*[@id='item_52b3985a70d58']/div[4]")`

Answer (score 0):

You an use Nokogiri to parse the page after retrieving it. Here is the example code:

```
m = Mechanize.new
result = m.get("http://google.com")

html = Nokogiri::HTML(result.body)
divs = html.xpath('//div').map { |div| div.content } # here you can do whatever is needed with the divs
                                                     # I've mapped their content into an array
```

Comment: Well, it didn't print anything but it also didn't give any errors. Is it just a matter of figuring out what went wrong with the xpath now?

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm simply trying to print the text inside the <div>. I though XPath would be an easy way since I don't know how to specify the exact thing I'm looking for with HTML. The XPath corresponds to the first "X,XXX crafted" number in this image: http://i.imgur.com/RJnZ22s.png

Comment: i have writted the example code in the answer. i hope it help you. im sorry I gotta go now. I will check in tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things wrong:

1. The ID doesn't exist on that page. Try this to see the list of tag IDs available:

   ```
   require "open-uri"
   require 'nokogiri'

   doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://store.steampowered.com/promotion/snowglobefaq"))
   puts doc.search('[id*="item"]').map{ |n| n['id'] }.sort
   ```
2. The correct chain of methods is `agent.page.xpath`.

Because there is no sample HTML showing exactly which tag you want, we can't help you much.